# Vrapper Vim Plugin for Eclipse not Working for any Vim commands

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, vim

Installed Vrapper plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace without errors. Vrapper version 0.40.0. Eclipse Kepler running on MacBook version 10.9.1, with Mavericks OS.

The Vrapper icon shows up as expected in the toolbar. No errors in the console. When toggled, the Vrapper button does nothing - no vim commands run in Eclipse whether the button is toggled or not.

I've read some issues about Eclipse's key bindings superseding Vrapper's, so I restored Eclipse's key bindings to the default settings. Still, no vim commands work in Eclipse. I've restarted Eclipse, as well as my Macbook. I've also tried installing Vrapper from the Install New Software dialogue window, where I manually pasted in the url to Vrapper's repository at SourceForge.

Any ideas on how to get Vrapper working?

Comment: Do you have any valid reason for asking that question here instead of the project's issue tracker?

Comment: I asked on the project's Github issue tracker as well - thought asking in both places would increase my chances of finding a solution. Still have not solved this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded from an 8 GB to a 16 GB Macbook, tried the Vrapper plugin on the new machine, and it works wonderfully.

On my old machine, I experienced constant memory problems - Eclipse often would freeze and I would need to Force Quit and restart Eclipse. Unsure if the memory issues I experienced on my old machine caused or contributed to Vrapper not working, but that is my best guess as to the cause of my problems with Vrapper.

Needless to say, Vrapper works on my new machine.